# My friend's cat stopped eating

Tags: cats, health, eating, emergency

My friend's cat's  birthday is April 21st, 2020. She’s drooling, not eating, growling at her food and losing weight. At first the vet said she has a respiratory infection, fever and ulcers in her mouth; then put her on antibiotics, liquid and powder with food, but she’s still the same. It’s been about 3 weeks, the vets also said her teeth were fine, she’s in emerge now, but still nothing; the vets are saying she’s fine.

Comment: Your friend needs to take the cat to another vet immediately.

Comment: She has been brought into the vet emerge, she’s not okay, but every vet has said she was fine but she’s not

Comment: You need *another* vet. Stop going to the same one.

Comment: she has brought in her cat to 3 different vets

Comment: Maybe consider food allergies and poisoning. Feed her from a glass or porcelain bowl and try different brands of food, at the moment preferably "sensitive" foods. Then search for anything that could be poisonous for cats (which can be many things harmless to humans): house plants, onion or garlic in her food, cleaning agents used to wipe the floors and any surfaces she might walk on, air refresheners, any essential oils anywhere in the house. Make sure there are no long forgotton pest baits (like rat poison) anywhere in the house, including the cellar and attic.

Comment: Lilly plants are poisonous to cats, even the pollen.

Comment: Try feeding her baby food the meat kind

Comment: Your friend needs to be fully honest with the vets. Disclose everything--plants in the house, chemicals in the house, any changes, etc. Many common houseplants (like the aforementioned lilies) are highly toxic, as are many common household cleaners (Lysol in particular is extremely toxic to cats). If the vet doesn't know what the cat may have been exposed to, they can't help.